# JQuery UI Sortable - No Duplicates Allowed

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following html:

```
<div id="cats-and-links">
    <div class="cat favorites">
        <h2>Favorites</h2>
            <ul class="ui-sortable">
               <li class="place-holder info">To add items to your favorites drag them over to this list from their original list.</li>
            </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="cat">
        <h2>Participants</h2>
        <ul class="ui-sortable">
            <li data-id="1"><a href="/program/2/control-panel/demo1">Demo 1</a></li>
            <li data-id="2"><a href="/program/2/control-panel/demo2">Demo 2</a></li>
            <li data-id="3"><a href="/program/2/control-panel/demo3">Demo 3</a></li>
            <li data-id="4"><a href="/program/2/control-panel/demo4">Demo 4</a></li>
            <li data-id="5"><a href="/program/2/control-panel/demo5">Demo 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br class="clear">
</div>
```

I have the following jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var place_holder = $('.place-holder');
    var fav = $('.favorites ul');
    var cat = $(".cat ul");

    cat.sortable({
            connectWith: fav,
            cursor:'move',
            helper:'original',
            placeholder:'ui-state-highlight',
            receive: function(event, ui){
                console.log(ui);
                ui.item.addClass('added');
                if(ui.item.hasClass('added')){
                    fav.sortable('option', 'revert', true);
                    cat.sortable('option', 'revert', true);
                }
                //console.log(ui.item.attr('data-id'));

                //ajax here to get the list item favorited.
            },
            over: function(event, ui){
                place_holder.hide();
            },
            stop: function(event, ui){
                if(fav.children().length == 1){
                    place_holder.show();
                }
            },
            remove: function(event, ui){
                ui.item.clone().appendTo(fav);
                $(this).sortable('cancel');
            }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

I would like to fix two problems.  One of the problems I have tried to fix with by "adding a class" to the original item and not letting it be added again. So the issues:

1. Do not allow an item from one list ("Participants") to be moved to the other list ("Favorites") if the item has already been added to the "Favorites" list.
2. Do not allow drag drop sorting in the ("Participants") list.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I have solved both of my problems with the following jQuery.  Text response for the solution:

1. I loop thru the items looking for added, if the class 'added' is on the element it is a duplicate.
2. Made the "Favorites" list sortable and the other list "Participants" draggable.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*$('#cats-and-links').masonry({
          // set columnWidth a fraction of the container width
          columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
            return containerWidth / 4;
          },
          gutterWidth:10,
          isFitWidth:true,
          itemSelector:".cat"
    });*/
    var place_holder = $('.place-holder');
    var fav = $('.favorites ul');
    var cat = $(".cat:not(.favorites) ul li");

    cat.draggable({
        connectToSortable: fav,
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });

    fav.sortable({
            cursor:'move',
            helper:'original',
            placeholder:'ui-state-highlight',
            receive: function(event, ui){
                console.log(ui);
                ui.item.addClass('added');
                if(ui.item.hasClass('added')){
                    $(this).children().each(function(){
                        if($(this).hasClass('added')){
                            $(this).remove();
                        }
                    });
                }
                //console.log(ui.item.attr('data-id'));

                //ajax here to get the list item favorited.
            },
            over: function(event, ui){
                place_holder.hide();
            },
            stop: function(event, ui){
                if(fav.children().length == 1){
                    place_holder.show();
                }
            }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```